# How to get data from qlik Engine api with dates

Tags: qliksense

I am very new to Qlik Engine API. I am trying to implement an application that takes a dimension, measure and a time frame details( like last week, 4 days etc.) as input gives the data as output.

I am using web sockets and requesting with json and getting response back.

I have tried with HyperQube as mentioned in https://community.qlik.com/thread/204384. So I have given `Date` as dimension with some measure and I am able to get the data, but how to retrieve data of specific time period like I want Impressions count for last 7 days of each day.

Is there any best resources on what json needs to be sent to Engine to get the response of data.

I am seeing in documentation like `qlik.OpenApp` so what is the javascript library of that `qlik` I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can pass date ranges and make a query with Dimensions and Measures like below in the qlik expression.
`sum({<Date_Dimension={"$(= '>=' & '8/1/2018' & '<=' & '8/5/2018')"}>}Measure)`

It will Fetch the Measure value within the given dates.